# how to add fieldset to profile

Tags: civimember, profile, contacts

I added a multi-record field set to individual contacts:

> Field set name = Organizational Affiliations
>
> - Field 1 = Organization Name
> - Field 2 = Position or Title

...and see I can now add multiple affiliates to an individual via site/civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&ct=Individual.

How do add that field set to a profile?  It seems I can only add individual fields, not a set of fields, to a profile?

I intended to put this field set in a profile because the profile can be embedded in the contribution page for membership signup forms.  If there's another way new members can enter this data without using a profile that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way you can add a data (field) set en masse.... you need to add each field in the data set individually.

Comment: hi @k3ix - thanks for your response.  Is this true that fieldsets can not be added to profiles?... then I should accept this answer?

Comment: Alec, I just went to CiviCRM's 4.6 demo sandbox and confirmed that such a capability hasn't been added.  If this answers your question, then yes, accept the answer.